# Search XML, Base64, UTF-8 string in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, utf-8, base64

I have column that contains a dataContract XML string like this :

```xml
<ReportHandler.ReportWrapper
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Client.Main.GUI.Report">
    <ClassInfoList
        xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Service.External.ServiceContracts.Internal.Report" />
    <Report>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</Report>
</ReportHandler.ReportWrapper>
```

Now I need to pickout and decode the inner base64 UTF-8 string within the XML tag to search for specific data.

> [base64 UTF-8 string]

The best solution seems to be to creat a SQL StoredProcedure with a coursor and run through each row, extract the base64 string with CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING, then decode the inner base64 UTF-8 string.

So something like this :

```
DECLARE @id INT)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    //Find start index with CHARINDEX('<Report>', Column) and end index with CHARINDEX('</Report>', Column)
    //Use SUBSTRING on column with start and end index found to get Base64 string
    //Convert the [Base64 UTF-8 to searchable string Select Convert Cast xs:base64Binary][1] Mybe we need to convert to UTF-8 as well some way.
    //Do a select against the result string to see if it contains specific data
    //If it does contain specific data, log it to another table with simple insert
END
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Is there a better way to get this done?

Comment: What is the problem with doing the same in a query, as opposed to a cursor? Or do the other way round, encode and base64 your "specific data" and then look for it with a simple `charindex`, which will work if you are happy with case-sensitive comparisons and your base64's do not contain readability new lines?

Comment: *"The best solution seems to be to creat a SQL StoredProcedure with a coursor "* I very much doubt that using a `CURSOR` to loop through the data row by (agonising) row is going to be the "best" solution. SQL is a set based language, it excels at set based solutions, and a loop is the completely opposite of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have an XML document embedded inside another one, encoded from UTF-8 to base64.**

To convert it back, do the following steps

- Select the value using XQuery `(/ReportHandler.ReportWrapper/Report/text())[1]`
- You need to add the namespace using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Client.Main.GUI.Report')`
- Convert from base64 to `varbinary` using `xs:base64Binary()`
- Convert that to to `xml` using `CONVERT`

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Client.Main.GUI.Report')
SELECT CONVERT(xml,
    @xml.value(
    'xs:base64Binary((/ReportHandler.ReportWrapper/Report/text())[1])',
    'varbinary(max)')
)
```

> Replace `@xml` with your column name in a `SELECT` table query

Result

```xml
<XtraReportsLayoutSerializer SerializerVersion="19.2.7.0" Ref="0" ControlType="MyApp.Client.Main.GUI.Report.repReport, MyApp, Version=5.13.0.20857, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Name="repReport" Margins="100, 80, 20, 100" PaperKind="A4" PageWidth="827" PageHeight="1169" Version="19.2" RequestParameters="false" EventsInfo="repReport,BeforePrint,repReport_BeforePrint;repReport,DesignerLoaded,repReport_DesignerLoaded"><Bands><Item1 Ref="1" ControlType="DetailBand" Name="Detail" HeightF="206.624985" TextAlignment="TopLeft" Padding="0,0,0,0,100" /><Item2 Ref="2" ControlType="PageHeaderBand" Name="PageHeader" HeightF="30" TextAlignment="TopLeft" Padding="0,0,0,0,100" /><Item3 Ref="3" ControlType="PageFooterBand" Name="PageFooter" HeightF="30" TextAlignment="TopLeft" Padding="0,0,0,0,100" /><Item4 Ref="4" ControlType="TopMarginBand" Name="topMarginBand1" HeightF="20" /><Item5 Ref="5" ControlType="BottomMarginBand" Name="bottomMarginBand1" /></Bands></XtraReportsLayoutSerializer>
```

You can use XQuery on that result also, if you want.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5dd827957e195ed694ad4334a59ee25)

Comment: Thanks, I have tested this but I get a column with only null, pleas see my Edit in main post.

Comment: Works for me in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=770319ec6db8a2b5223de62d3148f34e) using the XML you provided. is the XML the same, including namespaces? I must say, i don't understand why you needed the temp table, you could select straight out of `patdok_sida`

Comment: Found the problem, a typo. The problem is that the column in patdok_sida is not XML but VARCHAR(MAX) and its not possible to use XQuery on this type.

Comment: You do it like this `SELECT ..... FROM patdok_sida ps CROSS APPLY (VALUES (TRY_CONVERT(xml, ps.layout_utskrift) )) AS v(xml_layout)`

Comment: That worked great! Right now there is no UTF-8 handling, might that be needed?